# how to assign id based on array values

Tags: php

I am learning php please help.

I am storing values in an array and then I am trying to get the id of another array checking the value in array like this:

```
$arr_folders = ['one', 'two', 'whatever'];

$id_one = '';
$id_two = '';
$id_whatever = '';
foreach ($tree as $key => $value) {
  if($value['name'] == 'one'){//how to check dynamically?
    $id_one = $value['id'];
  }
  if($value['name'] == 'two'){//how to check dynamically?
    $id_two = $value['id'];
  }
  if($value['name'] == 'whatever'){//how to check dynamically?
    $id_whatever = $value['id'];
  }
}
echo $id_whatever;
```

How can I check the arrays values dynamically. I mean I want to check if the value exist in array then assign their id.

Comment: You can use in_array() function to fix this

Comment: *"I mean I want to check if the value exist **in array** then assign their id."* <- There you go

Comment: could you please provide dummy data with array, then I would prepare example for you..

Comment: @SunnyS.M I have updated my question.

Comment: @Anant No. I don't want to check statically for one, two, or whatever. I want to check if array value exists there and assign their id correspondingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `in_array` to check whether the element is exist or not in another array, and if found you can create dynamic variable based on `$value['name']` containing `$value['id']` as required.

```
$tree = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'one'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'two'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'three']
];
$arr_folders = ['one', 'two', 'whatever'];
foreach ($tree as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value['name'], $arr_folders)) {
        ${'id_'.$value['name']} = $value['id'];
    }
}
echo $id_one;
```

Working Example: https://eval.in/596034

Note: make sure `$value['name']` doesn't contain spaces or any other characters which aren't allowed to declare variable names.

Comment: Thanks. I need one other help. I have dash in arr_folders value for eg. whatever-there. now ${'id_'.$value['name']} will cause problem. How can I use?

Comment: you can replace those with underscore in runtime, like `str_replace('-', '_', $value['name'])`

Comment: use `explode`, if you have more questions, you can ask separate questions

Answer (score 0):

Try using array search

For example:

```
<?php 
$arr_folders = ['one', 'two', 'whatever'];

foreach ($tree as $key => $value) {
  if (($key = array_search($arr_folders, $value)) !== false) {
    return $arr_folders[$key];
  }
}
echo $id_whatever;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you're asking how you can check for the contents of one array (in this case, `[one, two, whatever]`) in the middle of looping through the other array without hardcoding it.  If that's the case, I might try something like this:

```
$arr_folders = ['one', 'two', 'whatever'];
$id_folders  = ['', '', '']

foreach ($tree as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($arr_folders as $fkey => $fvalue) {  // f for folder, in this case
    if($value['name'] == $fvalue){
      $id_folders[$fkey] = $value['id'];
    }
  }
}
echo $id_folders[2];
```

There may be other more elegant or time-effficient solutions, but I think this captures the dynamic nature you're looking for while mirroring the actual process of the previous code.

Answer (score 0):

here is sample code :

```
<?php
$arr_folders = ['one', 'two', 'whatever'];
$tree= Array(Array('id' => 1,'name' => 'one'),
             Array('id' => 2,'name' => 'large'),
             Array('id' => 3,'name' => 'thumb'),
             Array('id' => 4,'name' => 'two'),
             Array('id' => 5,'name' => 'large'),
             Array('id' => 6,'name' => 'thumb')
        );

foreach ($tree as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value['name'],$arr_folders)){
        $searchedIds[] = $value['id'];
    }
}
print_r($searchedIds);
?>
```