# how to split stored variables name inside foreach

Tags: php

**How can i know the variables ?**

```
foreach($tree as $key => $value){
  if (in_array($value['name'], $arr_folders)) {
    ${'id_'.$value['name']} = $value['id'];
  }
  //how to know variables?
  $id_???
```

Currently I know the `$value['name']` ie. it may be one,two, three, etc. but how to use them

```
echo $id_one;
```

I wanted to know here to split them in an array. So i can use

`print_r($vars);` which would result `$id_one, $id_two,` etc..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Read it carefully

Comment: i have edited my question. i think this is clear now?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046534/how-to-assign-id-based-on-array-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
    $array = [];

    foreach($tree as $key => $value){
        if (in_array($value['name'], $arr_folders)) {
            $array[] = $value['id'];
        }
    }

    print_r($array);
```

Comment: Let me know if i can help you by fixing/explaining something. If this works out for you, mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: still not working as whast i expected.  i will find out what

Comment: still not working as what i am expecting. i will trhy myself and figure out and after i get solution i will accepted your answer.

Comment: What is not working as you expect? Let me know so i can fix my code

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking `$value['id']` in the if statement? This is getting kind of confusing so please edit your question and write how the `$tree` looks like and what you want your result to be

Answer (score 0):

You can find variables by code:

```
foreach (get_defined_vars() as $var_name => $var_value) {
    if(strpos($var_name, 'id_') ===0 ){
        //it's your variable
    }
}
```

But store variable in local scope look wrong.

May be better store to an other array:

```
$arIds = array();
foreach($tree as $key => $value){
  if (in_array($value['name'], $arr_folders)) {
     $arIds['id_'.$value['name']] = $value['id'];
  }
}
```